# How do we fetch second element by its position in Jquery using class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
DisablePaginationButton("first");
```

Above statement works fine and does the changed the first element fetched .

```
DisablePaginationButton("second"); ===> does not work 

function DisablePaginationButton(position) {
    $(".pagination a:" + position).addClass("disableButton");
    $(".pagination a:" + position).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    })
}
```

Could some one help me out on how to fetch the second element. Also the second last element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
function DisablePaginationButton(position) {
    var $elem = $(".pagination a:eq(" + (position - 1) + ")");
    $elem.addClass("disableButton");
    $elem.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    })
}
```

And call it like this

```
DisablePaginationButton(1);

DisablePaginationButton(2);
```

**EDIT**

Method `eq` is zero based. If you feel confortable with that, you could replace

```
(position - 1)
```

by

```
position
```

and call method like this

```
DisablePaginationButton(0);

DisablePaginationButton(1);
```

Comment: Why rape the index from zero-based rather than just pass the index proper?

Comment: @Grant Thomas: I imagined this could be clearer for him, it's not mandatory of course

Comment: Yeah, if I'm honest, I think it would make more sense to orient the method towards developers. In CSS, it may make sense to let a visual designer select the "1st element" rather than the "0th element" but not in code.

Comment: He could use `:nth-child()` instead of `:eq()` if the indexes are weird. I still think `.eq()` is the way to go, though!

Answer (score 2):

use `a:eq("+index+")` instead of first,second .. 0,1, ..

Answer (score 1):

Pass an index through instead and use [`eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), such as:

```
$(".pagination a:eq(" + position + ")")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.pagination').next();
```

examp. on fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/DwC3L/

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.eq()` over `:eq()`. I think it's much easier to work with and read. I'd also use a number over "first" and "second" and so on. There is a `:first` but there's no `:second` or `:third` or anything.

I'd do this.

```
var position = 1;
$('.pagination a').eq(position);
```

This would return the 2nd pagination link.

If you want the second to last you can pass a negative index.

```
$('.pagination a').eq(-2);
```